# LINQ to SQL: Updating fields based on foreign key relations during creation of new entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using WPF and Xaml

I'm creating a new row into a table. That table has a foreign key relationship. When the user types in the FK field I wan't others to update based on the relations. This I do believe happens automatically when I save to DB but I wan't to be able to see it right away.

To give an idea about what I'm trying to do let's assume it's a new person object I'm creating and one field is a Zip code. When a zip code is punched in the city where this zip code belongs should pop up.

In my viewModel I have the Zip code property

```
 public string ZipCode
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.ZipCode;
        }
        set
        {
            Model.ZipCode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ZipCode");
            RaisePropertyChanged("City");
        }
    }
```

and the City property

```
public string City
{
     get
     {
            return Model.ZipMasterTable.City;
     }
 }
```

This works in displaying the correct city for the data already in the table but doesn't update the City field until I commit to database. The user inputting the data however might need to know if he put the right zipcode in and wants to see the City field when inputting and before committing.

Is there any way I can get it updated using Linq to Sql ?

Comment: I am a bit confused. If `ZipCode` is a FK to the `City` table, there shouldn't be any `ZipCode` property in your entity but a Navigation property called `City`.

Comment: Well this was an example but there would be a table with 2 columns, ZipCode and City. Then in the Person table there would be a ZipCode column that is keyed to the ZipCode/City table. I called it ZipMasterTable in the example above. LINQ would automatically match the ZipMasterTable navigationproperty in the person model to the correct row, but not on creation time.

Comment: I am still confused. As I said, there would be no ZipCode property in Person. So, the only way to do it would be the following: Find the ZipMasterTable entry with the entered ZipCode and assign it to the ZipMasterTable property of Person.

Comment: Why do you say there would be no ZipCode property? ZipCode is a column in person table. LINQ to SQL exposes both the property used in FK relation and the relation itself.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an exception when you try to set ZipCode.  If its a foreign key to the ZipMasterTable, you shouldn't be allowed to change it if the ZipMasterTable has already been assigned an entity, you have to change the ZipMasterTable property instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is during creation only so I can do it. Textblock is locked when not new. I actually do this now by just attaching the table property when a legal postcode is set.

Comment: Does this have to be with linq-to-sql? Otherwise you can always keep a dictionary with zip and city and onchange of zip, you can populate the city textbox or field.

Comment: Well ZIpCode and City was really just an example of what I was trying to attain. In reality it's a DB table that will be changed from a 3rd party. I've found a solution that works and I'm ok with.